# Socket does not detect a client... updated

Tags: sockets, polling

I am new to network programming. I am trying to implement UDP connection.
My problem is this code. I got this from a book.

```
...
if (m_isConnected == false & m_socket != null && 
    m_socket.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead)) {
    // a client joined
    m_isConnected = true;
}
...
```

Everything is fine, but socket polling.
Socket.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead) <- this code is not working.
This function always return false, whether a client tries to get in or not.
Can anyone tell me why this happens? Give me some advice, please.

==========

I found out this works when I try to play, opening 2 game windows on the same device (my macbook). I used local IP addresses, like 192.169.0.1.
But when I tried it between my macbook and my smartphone(Galaxy note 2) under the same WIFI, it didn't work.
So I  turned off WIFI connection in my smartphone and opened 3G and tried it with my macbook, it crashed.
I guess I need to know something in order to connect 2 different devices.
Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: What language is this? and what API?

Comment: There isn't any such thing as a UDP connection.  UDP is a packet-based protocol and is connectionless.  (You can call connect() on a UDP socket but that just sets the default behavior for send() and recv() calls; you're better off using sendto() and recvfrom() anyway, and avoiding connect() when using UDP)

Comment: @EJP I forgot to say that. I'm using Unity3d and c#.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for your reply. I heard UDP doesn't need connection. But, I can realize someone is connected with that code and I need it. And someone says that it makes simple to communicate because I don't need to check who messages are from, if a connection is made.